# How to display multiple images in the before and after plugin?

Tags: plugins, images

As the title says, I need to know how to add multiple images in the before and after plugin,
The plugin allows me to add two images only, 
Is there is anyway to display multiple images with prev & next buttons in a slider?

Comment: Hello! Your question is pretty vague. What plugin are you working with? What do you mean by "before and after" plugin? Please provide additional details to help the community better answer your question.

Comment: I use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/twenty20/

Comment: Example : https://ps.w.org/twenty20/trunk/screenshot-5.png?rev=1970271

Comment: I want to be able to add multiple images not just two.

Comment: can anybody help me please

Answer (score -1):

Slick slider did the job for me with some modifications.